# spring boot get data from mysql table given by url

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot

I want to create simple app to search some data in specific table.
I've got one database and can connect to it.
Also when I hardcoded table name it works great.
But I want to make url like that:

```
/demo/{table}/{author}
```

It should work that i give specific table for eg. 'comedy' and next I set name of author for eg. 'smith'.

My booksRepository:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM :table WHERE author = :author",
        nativeQuery=true)
public List<Book> findByAuthor(@Param("author") String author, @Param("table") String table);
```

But it didn't work. I've got error:

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''comedy' WHERE author = 'Smith'' at line 1
```

It's adding ' to Query. Is there way to delete that? Is it possible or I need to put everything in one table?
Cheers :)

Comment: does every table have author?

Comment: yeah, I've already done that - just creating one really big table :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked it up, but it seems that the variables in the query SQL can only be used to insert quoted values, not unquoted identifiers like a table name.

Comment: seems legit. Thanks, I'm going to search some workaround :)